# I have a find command used in my script. command use - find . -type f -name "*.txt" -mtime +30. How does this command work? Does it consider day alone

Tags: shell, unix

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -mtime +30
```

Does this command consider day alone? Or day and time?

If I am executing the command on 12.00 pm, will it fetch files older than 30 days and created before 12 pm?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have unix machine at hand to test, but past experience leads me to believe that hours are not considered and simply cut off.  That means for me that a day therefor starts at 00:00 and lasts until 24:00 (midnight).
Also, -mtime is not creation time, but modify time.

```
find 
.             (= current directory)  
-type f       (= {and} files only)  
-name "*.txt" (= {and} all files with .txt extension)  
-mtime +30    (= {and} files modified greater than 30 days previously)
```

Executing that command on Jan 31 will return all files that were modified on or before any hour of Jan 1, and match the other criteria.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html